# There is a problem writing repository test code using jpa

Tags: jpa, junit5

When testing fetch join, the expected results are different from the actual service operation and the test code written.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Scrum {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDateTime deleteDate;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int currentMember;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int maxMember;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "scrum", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ScrumInfo scrumInfo;
```

This is a Scrum class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ScrumInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "scrum_id")
    private Scrum scrum;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String subject;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean isStart;
```

This is a class with Scrum information.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class ScrumRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ScrumRepository scrumRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ScrumInfoRepository scrumInfoRepository;

    private Team team;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        User user = User.builder()
                .email("test@test.com")
                .profileImage("ex")
                .nickname("ex")
                .isOnline(false)
                .type("kakao").build();
        userRepository.save(user);

        team = Team.builder()
                .user(user)
                .maxMember(15)
                .name("팀이름")
                .currentMember(1)
                .description("팀설명")
                .teamProfileImage("팀프로필사진")
                .build();
        teamRepository.save(team);

        Scrum scrum = Scrum.builder()
                .user(user)
                .team(team)
                .currentMember(1)
                .name("스크럼이름")
                .maxMember(15).build();
        scrumRepository.save(scrum);

        ScrumInfo scrumInfo = ScrumInfo.builder()
                .isStart(false)
                .scrum(scrum)
                .subject("주제").build();
        scrumInfoRepository.save(scrumInfo);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("삭제되지 않고 현재 팀에 속한 scurm 모두 조회")
    void 삭제되지_않고_팀에_속한_스크럼_모두조회(){
        // given
        // when
        List<Scrum> scrums = scrumRepository.findByTeamWithFetchJoinUserAndScrumInfoAndDeleteDateIsNull(team).get();

        // then
        Assertions.assertFalse(scrums.isEmpty());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(scrums.get(0).getScrumInfo());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(scrums.get(0).getUser());

        User fetchUser = scrums.get(0).getUser();
        Assertions.assertEquals("test@test.com", fetchUser.getEmail());

        ScrumInfo fetchScrumInfo = scrums.get(0).getScrumInfo();
        Assertions.assertEquals("주제", fetchScrumInfo.getSubject());

    }
```

This is the test code I wrote, where scrums.get(0).getScrumInfo returns null.
The problem is that getUser finds it well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGRHD.png)

```
@Transactional
    public void createScrum(String accessToken, Long teamId, CreateScrumRequestDTO dto) {
        Long userId = jwtUtil.getUserId(accessToken);

        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("유저 없음"));

        Team team = teamRepository.findById(teamId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new TeamNotFoundException("팀이 존재하지 않습니다."));

        try {
            // 스크럼 생성
            Scrum scrum = Scrum.builder()
                    .name(dto.getName())
                    .maxMember(dto.getMaxMember())
                    .currentMember(1)
                    .team(team)
                    .user(user).build();
            scrumRepository.save(scrum);

            // 스크럼 정보 생성
            ScrumInfo scrumInfo = ScrumInfo.builder()
                    .scrum(scrum)
                    .subject(dto.getSubject())
                    .isStart(false).build();
            scrumInfoRepository.save(scrumInfo);

            // 스크럼 참여자 정보 생성
            ScrumParticipant scrumParticipant = ScrumParticipant.builder()
                    .scrum(scrum)
                    .user(user).build();
            scrumParticipantRepository.save(scrumParticipant);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FailCreateScrumException("스크럼 생성에 실패하였습니다.");
        }
    }

    // 스크럼 팀 조회
    public ScrumRoomListResponseDTO findScrums(String accessToken, Long teamId) {
        Long userId = jwtUtil.getUserId(accessToken);

        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("유저 없음"));

        Team team = teamRepository.findById(teamId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new TeamNotFoundException("팀이 존재하지 않습니다."));

        InviteTeamList inviteTeamList = inviteTeamListRepository.findByUserAndTeamAndParticipantIsTrue(user, team)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NonParticipantUserException("해당 유저가 팀에 참여하지 않았습니다."));

        Optional<List<Scrum>> scrumList = scrumRepository.findByTeamWithFetchJoinUserAndScrumInfoAndDeleteDateIsNull(team);

        List<Scrum> scrums = scrumList.orElse(new ArrayList<>());
        List<ScrumRoomDTO> scrumRoomDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<scrums.size(); i++){
            Scrum s = scrums.get(i);
            if(s.getScrumInfo().getEndTime() == null){
                ScrumRoomDTO scrumRoomDTO = ScrumRoomDTO.builder()
                        .scrumId(s.getId())
                        .name(s.getName())
                        .profileImage(s.getUser().getProfileImage())
                        .maxMember(s.getMaxMember())
                        .currentMember(s.getCurrentMember())
                        .isRunning(s.getScrumInfo().getIsStart())
                        .nickname(s.getUser().getNickname()).build();

                scrumRoomDTOList.add(scrumRoomDTO);
            }
        }

        return new ScrumRoomListResponseDTO(scrumRoomDTOList);
    }
```

The first method above creates a scrum and
The second method is looking up Scrum. But here we are looking for scrumInfo correctly.

The configuration is the same, but I don't know why this problem occurs.

Below is the repository query I want to test.

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Scrum s JOIN FETCH s.scrumInfo JOIN FETCH s.user WHERE s.team = :team AND s.deleteDate IS NULL")
    Optional<List<Scrum>> findByTeamWithFetchJoinUserAndScrumInfoAndDeleteDateIsNull(Team team);
```